# Iterate through DataContext items without casting it to a viewmodel type

Tags: mvvmcross

Is their a way to access Items contained in a DataContext without having to explicitly cast it to this `ViewModel`.

Let's say I'm binding a `DataContext` on an MvxFrameControl view, then I obtain this DataContext in code-behind once it is binded. It will look like an anonymous object containing a list of Items that are known as the children of this `ViewModel`. Can I swiss-bind these items, or some properties of this DataContext to another object, and so on?

I.e.

```
this.DelayBind(() => 
        {
            var data = DataContext;
            // It looks like data contains something called "Items" with a list of children viewModels.

        });
```

Can I access `DataContext.Items[0]`, or at least `DataContext.Items`, and bind it to an observable collection? Then finally swiss-bind some Items to views (`MvxFrameControl`s) on their `DataContext`?

So, summary: I'm curious if there is a way to work in code-behind with `DataContext` and its content so I could create a generic `MvxFrameControl` that would dispatch the data to custom views based on swiss-binding.

I have `ViewModels` containing lists of lists, and I want to handle a lot of situations in code-behind as I've experienced a lot of memory problems with `MvxListView`s containing `MvxListView`s.

[Edit]

This is actually what I was doing in my code that led me to think I should completely redefine how bindings are done. I'll write a minimal fake axml:

// Warning to anyone: this is a fake layout, don't use that

view_myactivity_layout.axml :

```
<LinearLayout>
    <MvxListView
         android:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/food_category_item"
         local:MvxBind="ItemsSource FoodCategories" />
</LinearLayout>
```

food_category_item.axml:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        local:MvxBind="Text Category" />
    <MvxListView
        android:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/list_of_food_for_a_category_item"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource FoodList" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_of_food_for_a_category_item.axml:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        local:MvxBind="Text NameOfThatFood" />
    <MvxListView
        android:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/list_of_colors_for_that_food_item"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource FoodList" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[Etc...]

Nesting binded controls works well, but there are tons of GC happening when scrolling. So that's why I was thinking about making my own binding pattern using reflection for this case.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking... If you know there will always be an `Items` collection then you could use an `interface` to do this iteration? Alternatively, you could use Reflection to do this in your own code? If you are looking only within MvvmCross, you could use string based Swiss binding like `.To("-the description-")` or `.SourceDescribed("-the description-")`. However, really I'm not sure I understand your code from your description - so can't say much more on this - sorry.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I summarized a lot what I'm trying to achieve in my edit. I'm nesting lists in lists, and I'm doing bindings in the layout (My ViewModels are lists with lists with lists). Everything works fine, but it seems that at the moment there is a nested list, GC are called a lot during scrolling. A list of 30+ items with just 2 levels of list (parent / children) can ask for up to 400kb when being scrolled from top to bottom.